# AD get logged in user ip from username

Tags: windows, active-directory

Is there a way to get logged in user's ip address from Active Directory with its username? (except Security Event Logs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. AD doesn't know if someone is logged in currently anyway - it only has the last time the login was successfully used. Also, a user could be logged in on 30 different machines; which one do you care about? You need to have the right auditing enabled, and be able to trawl through all the DC logs.

Comment: Which auditing settings should be enabled? I mean if I care all users logged in all machines.